# Asking for sabbatical vs. resigning to explore a different working field

Tags: resignation, sabbatical

This is a longer story. But I try to explain the most important details.

**summary**

My company doing business in some high tech (let's call it field of work **A**) offered me to change my fixed-term contract into a permanent position while I was trying to get internships for the time after the end of my contract to try out a different field of working (**B**). I now have to decide whether to negotiate a sabbatical or to resign from my current contract. (Third option: give up my plans and stay at my company)

*Central question: How do I get my internship for something different while keeping the doors in my current company open for coming back if my excursion fails?*

**longer explanation**

I'm currently employed, having a fixed-term contract over 2 years, and it ends in little more than 6 month (end of March 21).

While the 2 years duration is basically driven by legislation (fixed-term contracts can't last longer by law) it is mostly considered an extended probationary period. I have talked to colleagues and workers representation to find out that my company usually offers a permanent position just three month before the end of the fixed-term contract to comply with legislation again.

I had to assume, that it was very likely (>90%) to get an offer for a permanent position then. I have little to complain.

Now, I wanted to try out another type of job. I've been thinking about working in **B** for over 3 years now. To work in **B** I have to go to university for another two years, but also to do 4-6 month of internship in advance to get access to that postgraduate study.

Just after having sent out my first applications for internships in **B**, my boss asks me during our monthly regular meeting, why I did not ask for a permanent position yet. Eventually he pried out of me that it was a different work I wanted to try and that there are chances I could not return to them.

He wasn't happy but kept his countenance. I said, that I thought it would be an option to let the fixed-term contract end, do my "things" (my internships, but I didn't want to pronounce it) and then make a new contract, if they still wanted to employ me. It seemed to me that he considered this idea as rather ludicrous and said that we could negotiate a sabbatical instead. This is rather generous, but he said it in the heat of the moment and I think it was not well well-considered. We agreed to discuss that topic in the next monthly call again.

In the meantime I found out, that it will be difficult to match the beginning of the internship to the end of my fixed term contract, so it may be necessary to leave my current position earlier or having a gap between **A** and **B**. Considering that it might very well be a good choice to gain a permanent position and opting for a sabbatical then. But I have my doubts they will offer me a longer sabbatical after just working for them over 2 years. And if so, I also have a bad feeling about taking such an offer and later saying: "sorry guys, it was nice you kept my position open for 4 month, but I decided to go for university again now".

If I were sure to work in **B** is the best, my decision was very simple. Resign, start internship and go to university again. But I can't know, before I have done that internship, I think. And if I realize, that **B** was a stupid idea, I like the idea to go back to my current company.

I'm in a pinch now. How much should I disclose my plans about field **B** to allow my employer to make an informed decision? Should I take the permanent position with an option on a sabbatical if they offer it? What increases my chances for getting a job later at my current company if I learn that **B** is not, what I want?

Some perhaps relevant indications might be:

- my company is hiring constantly and they don't get enough people. As they build essential things for the digital age, this won't decline, a global depression exempt.
- I asked co-workers about the fixed-term contracts. Getting offered a permanent position 6 month before end is considered very rare.
- I'm deeply entrapped in a big project. But until the end of my fixed-term contract, the essential things could be finished if we are lucky.
- Notice period is 2 month from end of month. I.e. to leave after e.g. 28.2.2021, I had to resign before the end of 2020.

As I'm currently 45 yo it is not granted to get a job elsewhere in **A** when I'm not taken back by my current company.

Comment: Welcome new user - I would urge you to drastically shorten ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would encourage you to consider practicality.  You're 45 right now.  After about 2.5 years of university, internship, and delay (which presumably will cost you money overall) you'll be at least 47.  How many more years would you have to work in this new field, after that?  When *do* you hope to retire?  For that matter, how plausible would it be for you to find a job in that field?  For those employers who are interested in hiring someone fresh out of school, are they going to want someone who's almost 50?

There are a lot of real, practical issues around changing carer field at your age.  You'd also be abandoning a solid, current job that you apparently like reasonably well to do it, and seeking something that may not pan out.  All of this has some pretty significant implications for your life overall.

If the practicality of the matter does not move you, and you really, really want this thing, then go ahead and take the sabbatical.  Be *grateful* to your boss for offering you this chance.  He is giving you a great gift.  Do your internship, and then come back, and *don't* leave immediately.  Settle back into your old role before you make the decision to abandon it, and then take the time and space that solid employment gives you to make sure that you have your practicalities in place (that you have enough money to make it through your schooling, that you have an understanding of what the job market's going to look like afterwards... basically, that you're ready for this).  By the time you've done that, you'll have been back long enough that it's hopefully no longer jarring if you do decide to go back to school... and it'll let you line up your dates better, too.